# Changing underlined text font in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a large PPT file that I need to format to certain specifications. I need all font to be Arial 14 unless the text is underlined. If the text is underlined I need the font to be 32. Here's my attempt at it so far, I have the Arial 14 part working, but I can't figure out how to select just the underlined text. If anyone has any thoughts it would be appreciated. I also have zero experience with VBA outside of this project, though I am familiar with c++

```
Sub use()
Dim s As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each shp In s.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
        With shp
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
            If .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Underline = True Then
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 32
            End If
            With .TextFrame.TextRange
             .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
             End With

        End With

        End If
    Next shp
Next s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    For x = 1 To Len(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
                        If oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(x, 1).Font.Underline = True Then
                            With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(x, 1)
                                .Font.Size = 32
                            End With
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Screenshot

[image]